# Sharing JFrame between Lotus Notes Agent, allowing data to be passed

Tags: java, swing, lotus-notes, lotus, agent

I'm trying to share a `JFrame` between instances of a Lotus Notes Java agent. I would like to re-use my window instead of recreating it each time my agent executes.

My class, `RaiseJira`, extends `JFrame`, which extends Frame. When I run the following code, I get a `ClassCastException`.

```
Frame[] fs = Frame.getFrames();
for (int i = 0; i < fs.length; i++) {
    if (fs[i].getName().equals("RaiseJira")) {
        RaiseJira f = (RaiseJira) fs[i];
    }
}
```

If I cast it to a `JFrame`, it works fine and I have access to the `JFrame` methods. I'm trying to pass data to it using `RaiseJira` methods, so it needs to be of the correct type.

Am I missing something with downcasting? Also, am I missing an easier way of passing data to a common `JFrame` from separate agents?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/2587435). There are other options. Not sure I really understand your question from the description, but check out some of the options from the accepted answer.

Comment: How are you instantiating the JFrame (eg. Document, Agent, etc) and what version of Notes?

Answer (score 1):

> When I run the following code, I get a ClassCastException.

In your `if` condition:

```
if (fs[i].getName().equals("RaiseJira"))
```

Checking the frame's name doesn't make sense in this context because you can have a `JFrame` which is not instance of `RaiseJira` class but its name is set to "RaiseJira".  For instance:

```
JFrame trollFrame = new JFrame("He he");
trollFrame.setName("RaiseJira");
```

Then you'll have a `ClassCastException` here:

```
if (fs[i].getName().equals("RaiseJira")) { // This is true
    RaiseJira f = (RaiseJira) fs[i]; // ClassCastException because is a JFrame not RaiseJira instance
}
```

If you want to be sure if a given frame is actually an instance of `RaiseJira` class you should use `instanceof` operator (I'd also use [enhanced for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) but it's me):

```
for (Frame frame : Frame.getFrames()) {
    if (frame instanceof RaiseJira) {
        RaiseJira raiseJira = (RaiseJira) frame;
    }
}
```

#### Off-topic

I strongly suggest you read this topic: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice)

Comment: I've already upvoted that really interesting question (and some answerrs too). @mKorbel